# How to use tf.image.extract_patches for tensors other than images

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have to divide a tensor in to patches. I can use `tf.image.extract_patches` to convert`1x128x128x3` image to a `4x32x32x3`. Here the first element shows the batch size and for the input image, batch size is 1. It will produce 4 output images of size each `32x32x3`. Is there any tensorflow implementation which I can use to convert `1x128x128x5` to `4x32x32x5`. Here I want to divide a tensor of `1x128x128x5` into 4 tensors of each `4x32x32x5` small patches.